# How to join two dataframes in Scala and select on few columns from the dataframes by their index?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I have to join two dataframes, which is very similar to the task given here [Joining two DataFrames in Spark SQL and selecting columns of only one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38721218/joining-two-dataframes-in-spark-sql-and-selecting-columns-of-only-one)

However, I want to select only the second column from `df2`. In my task, I am going to use the join function for two dataframes within a `reduce` function for a list of dataframes. In this list of dataframes, the column names will be different. However, in each case I would want to keep the second column of `df2`.

I did not find anywhere how to select a dataframe's column by their numbered index. Any help is appreciated!

EDIT:

ANSWER

I figured out the solution. Here is one way to do this:

```
def joinDFs(df1: DataFrame, df2: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
  val df2cols = df2.columns
  val desiredDf2Col = df2cols(1)  // the second column
  val df3 = df1.as("df1").join(df2.as("df2"), $"df1.time" === $"df2.time")
      .select($"df1.*",$"df2.$desiredDf2Col")
  df3
}
```

And then I can apply this function in a `reduce` operation on a list of dataframes.

```
var listOfDFs: List[DataFrame] = List()
// Populate listOfDFs as you want here
val joinedDF = listOfDFs.reduceLeft((x, y) => {joinDFs(x, y)})
```

Comment: Can you make anl example of your data frames?

Comment: @Psidom: I figured out one solution. Please see the edit.

Answer (score 1):

To select the second column in your dataframe you can simply do:

```
val df3 = df2.select(df2.columns(1))
```

This will first find the second column name and then select it.

Answer (score 0):

If the `join` and `select` methods that you want to define in `reduce` function is similar to [Joining two DataFrames in Spark SQL and selecting columns of only one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38721218/joining-two-dataframes-in-spark-sql-and-selecting-columns-of-only-one) 
 Then you should do the following :

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
d1.as("d1").join(d2.as("d2"), $"d1.id" === $"d2.id").select(Seq(1) map d2.columns map col: _*)
```

**You will have to remember that the name of the second column i.e. `Seq(1)` should not be same as any of the dataframes column names.**

You can select multiple columns as well but remember the bold note above

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
d1.as("d1").join(d2.as("d2"), $"d1.id" === $"d2.id").select(Seq(1, 2) map d2.columns map col: _*)
```